# FROM Name MailItem Property

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I am trying to record tasks via sending an email in Outlook and I need to have the sender name in the body so the others know the task is assigned to them.

Using `MailObj.SenderName` does not use the FROM name it would look for the name of the recipient if I was replying.

Comment: Have you looked at the SentOnBehalfOfName property?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I tried that as well and it returned blank when I displayed the generated email. Could that be due to our email accounts being set up via Exchange?

Comment: For a new mail? These properties will be empty - they are populated when the message is actually sent.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko ah okay. I didn't actually try sending that message due to the name returning blank. I will try both properties and actually send the message and see what happens and report back.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I just tried sending the message with both `objmsg.SentOnBehalfOfName` and `objmsg.SenderName` and both were still blank :(

Comment: Those properties are available only after the message is moved to the Sent Items folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the current user information, use `Application.Session.CurrentUser`.

Comment: That works to get the current user but it formats as "LastName, FirstName" is there a way to get the current user first name only? That is really the only part I need due to only having a dept of 10 people.

Comment: Nevermind I was able to find `Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.FirstName` that retrieved solely the first name.

Comment: Keep in mind that GetExchangeUser will return null if you are not working with Exchange.

Comment: All of the users of my macro are on Exchange :) but definitely something for others to keep in mind.